# How do I itreate between X number of threads endlessly

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I am reading from 1 to 4 devices and I connect to each device and start a thread to read data.
I want to create a while loop that runs thread unit1, unit2 etc then starts again. I all so need to set a timer to read all the devices say every 5 seconds.

My code works to read and send the data i am having an issue understanding how i can create a while loop to read the units forever.

```
thread_list = []
ports = ['/dev/ttyXRUSB0']
for item in ports:
  #setup conection  
  client = EPsolarTracerClient(method = 'rtu', port = item, baudrate = 115200, timeout = 0.2 )
  #client = ModbusClient(method = 'rtu', port = item, baudrate = 115200, timeout = 0.2 )
  client.connect()
  #read config from device
  epstime = client.read_rtc()
  sync_date = datetime.datetime.now()

  #write config to device
  client.write_rtc(sync_date)

  #create and start thread for device
  thread = threading.Thread(target=readunit,args=(client,))
  thread_list.append(thread)
  thread.start()
  # below is just leftover from old code but it is where i want to start the loop 
while client.connect:
  # readunit(client) # old code

   sleepTime = 5

   sleep(sleepTime)
```

I need to run each thread every X seconds. and repeat 
for ever..
For example

Thread1
Thread2
....
sleep x seconds.
repeat

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating 2 separate functions and threading them, and then use `Timer` function to call them after 5 seconds, like this,

```
from threading import *
import time

def function1():
    while(True):
        print "1"
        time.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds      

def function2():
    while(True):
        print "2"
        time.sleep(5) # wait 5 seconds

# create threads
t = Timer(5.0, function1) # start the thread after 5 seconds
t2 = Timer(5.0, function2)
```

Comment: Changed to thread to process and created while loop in function. Now it works